# How to avoid first byte timeout with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, proxy, cdn

I have an application in RubyOnRails, proxied by a NGINX server that is behind a CDN service. The CDN has a limitation that if the response first byte does not arrive in 60 seconds, the CDN server responds:

`Error 503 first byte timeout`

The problem is that I do have some requests that take more than 60 seconds to be processed on the Rails side. Is there a way to hack the response, sending a few bytes before the response finish its processing? How?

Answer (score 0):

Given this will be stored on CDN, we can assume this is public content, and as such, it's a very long request period in that case. You should be aiming to keep public requests to under a second.

One option would be to use a CDN with "push zones" so you can generate the content as slowly as you like, and then push the content to the CDN for storage near the user. This is assuming there's a small number of fixed resources rather than dynamic content with multitude parameters.

Beyond that, I would look at ways to optimise your response time via caching and so on.